# Array print function

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a function that prints the elements of an array. I set it up so it calculates the size of the array, but I cannot figure why it doesn't work. Can you give me some suggestions?
Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void print_array(string s){
    for(int i = 0; i < ( sizeof(s) / sizeof(s[0]) ); i++){
        cout << s[i] << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    string names[5] = {"Dante", "Greg", "Bob", "Victor", "Saber"};
    print_array(names);
}
```

Comment: You're passing in (and expecting) a `string`, not an array of `string`s.

Comment: Tip: Use `std::vector` as a default for array-type things. This container includes length information and works well with `for(auto x : vec)` type iteration.

Comment: How can I modify it to work? I am a beginner to C++.

Comment: `
void print_array(vector<string> s){
    for(int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++){
        cout << s[i] << "\n";
    }
}`

Comment: Read the compiler's error messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Be aware that there are many questions similar to this that have received answers.

As mentioned in a comment, you would need to specify the size of the array if you plan on passing it into a function, because the compiler will look at it not as an array of strings (string s[]), but as a pointer to strings (string s*). Thus, you would need to modify it a little like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void print_array(string s[], int size){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        cout << s[i] << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    string names[5] = {"Dante", "Greg", "Bob", "Victor", "Saber"};
    print_array(names, sizeof(names) / sizeof(names[0]));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Simple and to the point. So, the solution is to calculate the size of the array before passing it to the function.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a string instead of an array of strings. You could modify your code by using vectors like this:

```
void print_array(const std::vector<std::string> &vector){
    for (const auto &string : vector) {
        std::cout << string << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> names = {"Dante", "Greg", "Bob", "Victor", "Saber"};
    print_array(names);
}
```

Using vectors allows you to use auto generated for loops, wich are easy to read and use.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't study about vectors yet, they seem to make things much easier for us!